# Apply fade effect on SCRecorder segments with AVAudioMix

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine

I'm trying to fix an issue I have with the awesome SCRecorder library for iOs. The issue is that when I record a segment with the camera, I can hear a "pop" or "click" sound at the very beginning of each video segments.

To fix that, I would like to apply a "fadeIn" effect on the audio at the beginning of each segments, so I can't hear these "clicks" anymore.

Here is my code until now :

```
func setFadeAudioSegments() -> SCRecordSession
{
    let newSession = SCRecordSession()

    for seg in (recorder.session?.segments)! {
        let segment = seg as! SCRecordSessionSegment

        let audioTrack = segment.asset?.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first
        let inputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)

        let timeR = CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMake(0,1), CMTimeMake(5, 1))
        inputParams.setVolumeRampFromStartVolume(0.0, toEndVolume: 1.0, timeRange: timeR)

        newSession.addSegment(segment)
    }

    newSession.fileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    newSession.mergeSegmentsUsingPreset(AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }
    })

    return newSession
}
```

I have no error but it just doesn't fade the audio. Can someone help me?

Thanks :-) !